# What is this little door on the upper deck of the A380?

Tags: aircraft-design, airbus-a380

I found a little "door" on the upper deck of this A380:
[image]

Source: [Airliners.net](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Lufthansa/Airbus-A380-841/2570598/L/&sid=760e921a06af5d6640f3f59d59b02741)

What is the purpose of that door, hatch, whatever?

Comment: At a guess a ladder for the emergency exit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at Airbus's [diagram gallery](http://www.airbus.com/fileadmin/media_gallery/files/tech_data/AC/Airbus-AC-A380-Dec2014.pdf) on the A380, this image suggests that the panel is to store and deploy the emergency evacuation slides.

[image: Slide diagram]

This is also supported by another picture from the same document, in which similar doors are seen under each second row entrance.

[image: Door diagram]

Comment: Those planes are beasts!!! Saw one at an airport I connected through last week.

Answer (score 21):

It's for the emergency slide.

You can see it deployed here:

[image]

Source:  Airliners.Net

Comment: It seems only the upper deck slides have a separate door (I assume it's because they don't fit at the normal location in the door). But I don't see the difference in the picture.

Comment: @mins, I don't know, but the inward slant of the upper deck door might have something to do with it.

Comment: @JanHudec: From [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=rfpsBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA85&ots=It8vYx5vi_&hl=fr&pg=PA85#v=onepage), the reason is about the size of the slides (length and width). Also as the slides are used as rafts, they need to adapt to the 700 passengers need.

Comment: See [video of slide deployment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TitxtXsuUNk)

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom deck the slide is packed inside the doors, but on the top deck the are in a small compartment underneath the door.